# Doctrine2 - Generate From Database

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I successfully generated entities from an existing mysql database, but I fail when trying to generate repository classes.

My doctrine.config.php

```
$frapi_config = array(
    'database' => array(
        'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
        'user' => 'root',
        'password' => 'root',
        'dbname' => 'PizzaVan',
        'host' => 'localhost:3306'
    ),
    'doctrine' => array (
        // Base path is /src/frapi/
        'entitiesFolder' => "custom/Application/Model"
    )
);
```

My bootstrap.php

```
//bootstrap.php 
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

require_once dirname(__FILE__) . "/../vendor/autoload.php";
require_once "doctrine.config.php";

// Create a simple "default" Doctrine ORM configuration for Annotations
$isDevMode = true;

$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(array(__DIR__ . "/../" . $frapi_config["doctrine"]["entitiesFolder"]), $isDevMode, null, null, false);

// database configuration parameters
$conn = $frapi_config["database"];

// obtaining the entity manager
$entityManager = EntityManager::create($conn, $config);
```

My cli-config.php

```
require_once "bootstrap.php";

return \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\ConsoleRunner::createHelperSet($entityManager);
```

As said before, if I run 2 commands from the console

```
./vendor/bin/doctrine orm:convert-mapping --namespace='custom\\Application\\Model\\' --force --from-database annotation .
```

and

```
./vendor/bin/doctrine orm:generate-entities . --generate-annotations=true --generate-methods=true
```

I get Entities correctly created in the right folder. Now I would like to create custom RepositoryClass, but if I run

```
./vendor/bin/doctrine orm:generate-repositories .
```

I get this message : "No Repository classes were found to be processed".
Any solution? Thank you!